# How should Trends handle tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, trends

I was looking at [tag trends for different Ionic-related tags](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=ionic%2Cionic-framework%2Cionic2) and noticed strange rise & fall of [ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic) around 2015–2016. I then searched for the tag on SO and noticed it is a synonym for [ionic-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-framework). Presumably the synonymization happened early 2016.

Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or should [ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic) stats be retroactively added/merged with [ionic-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-framework)?